# My custom directive do not affect models bind to input type radio button in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-directive

I have written a custom directive that convert English numbers to my language [Farsi] numbers and add it to all my needed inputs and that work well with input type text but for input type radio it did not make any change

in template :

```
<div class="form-group" >
        <label> .. </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="customerPostCode" 
                    #customerPostCode="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="sCustomer.postCode" 
                    (change)="setCustomerAddress(i)"  
                    [value]="item.postCode" checked
                    appFarsiNum >
              {{item.postCode}}
        </label>
</div>
```

and in class directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFarsiNum]'
})
...
 private el: HTMLInputElement;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private farsiNum: FarsiNumPipe) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.el.value = this.farsiNum.transform(this.el.value);
  }
@HostListener("change", ["$event.target.value"])
  onChanges(value) {
    this.el.value = this.farsiNum.transform(value);
  }
```

How can I bind input type radio text to my custom directive?
any tips or helps will be appreciated

Comment: It would be great if you provide a stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkusnt
Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: @AsimHashmi Thank you for your comment I have created a project with the same problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t42bkg